# Handling zombie processes when using waitpid

Tags: ruby

I have the following method, the idea is to run a shell command and both stream output to stdout as its recieved and store the information as a variable so I can return a hash of the information, I found no standard way of doing this (you either get streaming or captured output).

It does this by creating a forks to stream the output and append to an IO pipe that I can read in at a later date.

```
def self.run_cmd(cmd)                                                       
  stdout_rd, stdout_wr = IO.pipe                                            
  stderr_rd, stderr_wr = IO.pipe                                            
  status = Open4::popen4(cmd) do |_pid, _stdin, _stdout, _stderr|           
    pids = []                                                               
    pids << fork do                                                         
      _stdout.each_line do |l|                                              
        print l                                                             
        stdout_wr.puts l                                                    
      end                                                                   
    end                                                                     
    pids << fork do                                                         
      _stderr.each_line do |l|                                              
        print l                                                             
        stderr_wr.puts l                                                    
      end                                                                   
    end                                                                     
    pids.each{|pid| Process.waitpid(pid)}                                   
  end                                                                       
  stdout_wr.close                                                           
  stderr_wr.close                                                           
  out = stdout_rd.gets                                                      
  out = '' if out.nil?                                                      
  err = stderr_rd.gets                                                      
  err = '' if err.nil?                                                      
  { stdout: out, stderr: err, status: status.exitstatus }                   
end
```

This works great in most scenarios but specifically `unzip` doesn't play well with this approach, what happens is after a fixed amount of output from zip it will stall at `stdout_wr.puts l`

I've observed that when the ruby process has stalled that a zombie unzip is visible when running `ps`

Is there any way I can make this work?
Is there a better way of doing this? I appreciate that its a complex solution and it must be easier.

My potential idea is that my IO pipe is running out of buffered space but I'm able to print 10,000 lines of output without issue.

Comment: Actually it does appear to be a buffering issue, if I print 10,000 log messages it does replicate the issue. I probably need to flush a buffer at some point to resolve the issue.